# Why is Next.js not revalidating specific tags with on-demand revalidation?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, app-router

i'm currently trying out new Next.js 13's app router. I'm on `next@13.4.4`. I'm trying to create dashboard so user can manage languages. I have problem with revalidation of fetch inside dynamic page.

I've got server component `LanguagePage` that fetches initial data from API and passes those data to client component `Datagrid`. For this fetch I added tag `languages`.

```
export default async function LanguagePage() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/languages", {
    method: "GET",
    next: {
      tags: ["languages"],
    },
  })

  const data = (await res.json()) as LanguageWithDefaultFlag[]

  return (
    <div className="grid items-start gap-8">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
          <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight">Languages</h1>
          <p className="text-muted-foreground">Manage your languages</p>
        </div>
        <Link
          className={buttonVariants({ variant: "default" })}
          href="/admin/languages/new"
          icon={Icons.add}
        >
          New language
        </Link>
      </div>
      <Separator />
      <DataTable initialData={data} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I also have created server component `UpdateLanguagePage`. In here I fetch data from API endpoint that returns single `Language` entity and I pass it to client component `LanguageForm`. This fetch has got its own tag `language-${id}`.

```
export default async function UpdateLanguagePage({ params: { id } }: Props) {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/languages/${id}`, {
    method: "GET",
    next: {
      tags: [`language-${id}`],
    },
  })

  const data = (await res.json()) as LanguageWithDefaultFlag

  const currentDatetime = new Date()

  return (
    <div className="grid items-start gap-8">
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-2">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight">Edit the language</h1>
        {currentDatetime.toLocaleTimeString("cs-CZ")}
        {data.code}
      </div>
      <LanguageForm initialData={data} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Once form is submitted, I send data to PUT endpoint where I update database accordingly and then revalidate 2 tags – `language` and `language-${id}`. `languages` tag is revalidated correctly therefore `LanguagePage` is up to date whereas `language-${id}` is not revalidated, or at least the `UpdateLanguagePage` displays the old data.

```
export const PUT = withErrorHandling(
  async (
    request: NextRequest,
    { params: { id } }: { params: { id: string } }
  ) => {
    await authGuard([UserRole.ADMIN])

    const body = await request.json()
    const data = createLanguageSchema.parse(body)
    const language = await prisma.language.upsert({
      where: {
        id,
      },
      update: data,
      create: data,
    })

    // get default language from redis cache
    const defaultLanguage = await getDefaultLanguage()

    // revalidation of next.js' cache tags
    revalidateTag("languages")
    revalidateTag(`language-${id}`)

    return NextResponse.json({
      ...language,
      isDefault: language.id === defaultLanguage,
    })
  }
)
```

Once I full refresh the page data is updated, but I suppose that this is dev server feature.

I have no clue what to do. Have anyone experienced same issue?

Comment: can you provide your api/route.ts file for reference?

Comment: @TomFan sure I just updated the question, take a look

Comment: +1 same thing happening to me, in my case though I have a page that renders in 30 languages. Revalidating will only work for 5-6, but not the other ones. I've tried calling res.revalidate on each language individually but it doesn't seem to work.